# D3.js v4 colors to names mapping

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I am working on a visualization like this one right now:

[Sunburst Sequence](https://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/766f8f6d31f645c39f488a0befa1e3c8)

In the snippet he is hardcoding the colors like

```
// Mapping of step names to colors.
var colors = {
  "home": "#5687d1",
  "product": "#7b615c",
  "search": "#de783b",
  "account": "#6ab975",
  "other": "#a173d1",
  "end": "#bbbbbb"
};
```

I want to define only the colors of the parents. The childrens colors should be a variation of the parents with less opacity. Somehow coded like:

```
var color = d3.scale.category20();
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

d3.heirarchy (https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#hierarchy) returns these properties for each node:

- node.depth
- node.parent

You could use **.depth** as an input to a function that determines fill opacity, eg higher depth = more opacity.
You could use **.parent** as an input to a function that iterates up to the parent that has parent: null, and set the colour based on that node's value.